# ADFS v2.0 : Finding errors referenced by the reference number

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0

I get a number of browser error messages using ADFS, all of the form.

> There was a problem accessing the
>   site. Try to browse to the site again.
>   If the problem persists, contact the
>   administrator of this site and provide
>   the reference number to identify the
>   problem. Reference number:
>   c14bcf7c-268d-46be-82c3-7c1d873c3df2

I have tried to find these in the event log to no avail.

How do you use the reference number to track down the errors?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Open the Event Viewer.  Navigate to 'Applications and Services Logs' -> 'AD FS 2.0' -> Admin.  In the 'View' menu, using 'Add/Remove Columns...', add the 'Correlation Id' column.  Look up the reference number 'c14bcf7c-268d-46be-82c3-7c1d873c3df2' in the 'Correlation Id' column.

(In some specific cases you get a 'Reference number' but no event in the AD FS 2.0 event log.  In my experience that is mostly when customizing the sign-in pages.)

Comment: One cause... ADFS 2.0 will emit this error if the relying party trust is not set up correctly.  The event viewer error message will show the value that must be set up in the ADFS config.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error on an AD FS proxy server where the time had gone out of sync.